# How to pass multiple parameters to @ValueSource

Tags: junit5, spring-boot-test

I'm trying to perform a parametrized JUnit 5 test, how to accomplish the following?

```java
@ParametrizedTest
@ValueSource //here it seems only one parameter is supported
public void myTest(String parameter, String expectedOutput)
```

I know I could use `@MethodSource` but I was wondering if in my case I just need to understand better `@ValueSource`.

Answer (score 8):

The documentation says:

> @ValueSource is one of the simplest possible sources. It lets you
> specify a single array of literal values and can only be used for
> providing **a single argument** per parameterized test invocation.

Indeed you need to use `@MethodSource` for multiple arguments, or implement the `ArgumentsProvider` interface.

Answer (score 7):

Another approach is to use `@CsvSource`, which is a bit of a hack, but can autocast stringified values to primitives. If you need array data, then you can implement your own separator and manually split inside the function.

```java
import org.junit.jupiter.params.ParameterizedTest;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.CsvSource;
import static com.google.common.truth.Truth.assertThat;

@ParameterizedTest
@CsvSource({
    "1, a",
    "2, a;b",
    "3, a;b;c"
})
void castTermVectorsResponse(Integer size, String encodedList) {
    String[] list = encodedList.split(";");
    assertThat(size).isEqualTo(list.length);
}
```

Comment: For my simple use-case where I had to pass 2 integers that worked great

Comment: I added an answer with a variation of this which can handle arbitrary arguments

Answer (score 5):

You need jUnit Pioneer and the `@CartesianProductTest`

- https://github.com/junit-pioneer/junit-pioneer
- https://junit-pioneer.org/docs/cartesian-product/

POM:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit-pioneer</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-pioneer</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Java:

```java
import org.junitpioneer.jupiter.CartesianProductTest;
import org.junitpioneer.jupiter.CartesianValueSource;

@CartesianProductTest
@CartesianValueSource(ints = { 1, 2 })
@CartesianValueSource(ints = { 3, 4 })
void myCartesianTestMethod(int x, int y) {
    // passing test code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `@CsvSource` with arbitrary amount of arguments:

```
@ParameterizedTest
@CsvSource({
        "1, a",
        "2, a,b",
        "3, a,b,c"
})
void castTermVectorsResponse(ArgumentsAccessor argumentsAccessor) {
    int size = argumentsAccessor.getInteger(0);
    List<String> list = argumentsAccessor.toList().stream().skip(1).map(String::valueOf).toList();
    assertThat(size).isEqualTo(list.size());
}
```